# Form doesn't open as expected on launch of Access

Tags: forms, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I've created an Access database that several users are using. It is located on a server so everybody has access to the same file. Until recently it was working just fine.

When you open the database a menu-form is supposed to open from which you can open the other forms.

One morning when nobody was using the database I performed some updates and bug fixing (not on the menu-form). I had already written (and tested) the vb-code so all I did was copy-paste it over the old code. I tested it and everything worked fine.

A few hours later i hear from the users that the menu-form doesn't open on launch. It doesn't even open by double clicking. However the other forms can be opened by double-clicking. The only way to open the menu is to open it in Design view and from there click Form view on the ribbon.

I have checked under Options > Current Database that the menu-form is selected.

All users (including me) are using Access 2010.

The strangest part is that the form opens as it's supposed to on my computer but not on the users' computers.

I'm pretty sure my code couldn't cause this, but I must have done something else without knowing. So now I am looking for a solution that makes the menu-form show on launch again.

Comment: Did you, by any chance, make a backup before you rolled it out?  You may have to revert to the backup and try re-adding the updates one piece at a time, each time ensuring that the database opens as expected.

Comment: In case you aren't aware, please note that for Access databases to support multiple concurrent users you ***must*** split your database into a back-end database (tables) linked to a front-end database (queries, forms, reports, code) and each user ***must*** have their own (local) copy of the front-end database file. No two users should ever directly open the same .mdb or .accdb file (e.g., by double-clicking it or doing File > Open in Access). More details [here](http://allenbrowne.com/ser-01.html).

Comment: +1 to Gord's comment. Yes, you should follow his advice immediately before you corrupt your database/start getting conflicting data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that the form opened on the screen to left of the primary screen. I probably moved it there during my updating and couldn't imagine this would happen. So it worked on my configuration (primary to the right and secondary to the left) but not for people with only one screen or even for people with primary on the left and secondary to the right.

The solution was for someone with the right configuration to open the database exclusively, move the form to the primary screen, save and close. Now it works for everyone again.

Answer (score 0):

You might try forcing a Compile off the Debug Menu in the IDE.  I’ve ran into instances where things act strange and a Compile fixes it.